# problem to connect at symfony by using xampp

Tags: symfony, command-line, xampp

When I make a project with xampp to use symfony and after I did composer create-project symfony/skeleton nameProject" -> the project is created. After I did "composer require webapp and it works.
But if I write localhost/nameProject in the browser I have not the page of symfony. I only see the name of my project's files.

What do I have to do to have my symfony page?

Thank you!

I did :

- composer "create-project symfony/skeleton nameProject"
- cd nameProject
- composer require webapp

But after I don't know which command I have to write to have symfony page!

Answer (score 0):

If you click the `public` folder in the file list you're seeing, you should see the Symfony welcome page for your project.

However, to also view other pages you may add to your project (which may have urls that do not actually exist in the file/folder structure so need to be mapped to the correct controller/method), you need a way to pass all incoming requests to the `index.php` file that's in the `public` folder. The Apache webserver that comes with Xampp doesn't automatically do this without additional configuration.

There's a couple of ways to fix this:

Most common is to use the Symfony binary ( https://symfony.com/download ) to run the project on your local pc and ignore the Apache webserver provided by Xampp. If you have the Symfony binary installed, go to the `nameProject` folder in the command prompt and run `symfony serve`. You can then view the project at http://127.0.0.1:8000

If you do not have the Symfony binary installed, you can do the same with the built-in php web server (Xampp should have added php to your path). Go to the `nameProject/public` folder in the command prompt and run `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`.
This also shows the project at http://127.0.0.1:8000 (http without an s).

Or if you do want to use the Apache webserver provided by Xampp, you can install the `apache-pack` for your project with `composer require symfony/apache-pack`. This adds an `.htaccess` file to the `public` folder that contains the additional configuration Apache needs to pass all incoming requests to the `index.php` file. You can then again view the project at http://localhost/nameProject/public (but now this also works if you add additional pages to your project).